# Anomaly in Priority Queue Custom Sort in C++

Tags: c++, queue, priority-queue, minmax-heap

I went through a couple of StackOverflow and Codeforces articles for custom sorting priority queues in C++. By default the C++ implementation is a MaxHeap , so it would output elements in decreasing order. I minor tweak adding `greater<int>` would pop ascendingly. I tried this out using my own comparator function, as below:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class comp{
    public:
bool operator()(const int &a,const int &b){
        return a>b;
    }
};
int main(){
    priority_queue<int,vector<int>,comp> pq;
    pq.push(5);
    pq.push(1);
    pq.push(8);
    while(!pq.empty()){
        cout<<pq.top()<<" ";
        pq.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the output as expected : `1 5 8`

But if I change this to:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class comp{
    public:
bool operator()(const int &a,const int &b){
        if(a>b)
            return true;
    }
};
int main(){
    priority_queue<int,vector<int>,comp> pq;
    pq.push(5);
    pq.push(1);
    pq.push(8);
    while(!pq.empty()){
        cout<<pq.top()<<" ";
        pq.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output changes to : `8 1 5`

I'm somehow not able to get this, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: turn on compiler warnings and pay attention to them

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes I did, the function reaches end of non-void i.e. has no return value, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to read the compiler warnings... you will see that `bool operator()(const int &a,const int &b)` if `a<=b` doesn't have a return statement... and that's Undefined Behavior

Instead you should do this:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class comp{
    public:
    bool operator()(const int &a,const int &b){
        if(a>b)
            return true;
        /* else */ return false;
    }
};
int main(){
    priority_queue<int,vector<int>,comp> pq;
    pq.push(5);
    pq.push(1);
    pq.push(8);
    while(!pq.empty()){
        cout<<pq.top()<<" ";
        pq.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: or simply `return a > b;` No need for an `if (condition) return true; else return false;`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes for sure, but that's the first snipped the OP have posted... so I suppose he want to use a `if`

Comment: @AlbertoSigigaglia d'oh. I thought the difference between the two is `<` vs `>`. Misread

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia That worked like a charm, the function had to return for a bool , which it wasn't, thanks. And yes I wanted to use an `if` because I might face some custom structs or classes in future.